# What is it called when you get a ticket for driving an automobile which is in sore need of repair?

Tags: united-states, traffic, colorado

I live in the United States
Specifically, the state of Colorado.

I am required to tell my new employer what crimes I have pled guilty to, or been convicted of in a court of law.

In Colorado, you can get a ticket for driving a badly damaged car.

If you drive a rust-bucket - a shit-box - then you can get a ticket for having a poorly maintained vehicle. I have done exactly that.

The punishment for this crime crime is a monetary fee + 2 points removed from the guilty party's driver's license.

What is the official name of this traffic offense in the veritable state of Colorado?

Answer (score 5):

**You (probably) did not commit a crime in Colorado.**

The answer to your question though is probably **Driving an unsafe vehicle**

[Colorado Revised Statutes Title 42. Vehicles and Traffic § 42-4-202](https://codes.findlaw.com/co/title-42-vehicles-and-traffic/co-rev-st-sect-42-4-202.html#)

> > (1) It is unlawful for any person to drive...on any highway any vehicle...which is in such unsafe condition as to endanger any person, or which does not contain those parts or is not at all times equipped with such lamps and other equipment in proper condition and adjustment as required in this section and sections...

The above is not a crime , it is

> > (5) Any person who violates any provision of this section commits a class A traffic infraction.

A class A traffic infraction is a civil violation.

Note that some driving offenses are crimes: In Colorado, driving more than 25 mph over the posted limit is a class 2 misdemeanor, and doing so in a constriction zone is a class 1 misdemeanor.

Also note that I say probably because it is possible that they charged you with something more extreme- reckless driving? violation of noise or pollution ordinances?- but for a fine small enough that you don't say, 2 points, and you did not have to go to court (you could have if you wanted for the ticket, but not required) it is very unlikely.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have committed a criminal act such as a hit and run or a crash involving a death, a traffic citation is not a crime crime. If you have received a citation, sometimes known as a ticket, you'll see that signing the citation and paying a fine is not an admission of guilt. You might want to edit out one of the "crime" entries from "crime crime."

The "official name" of the traffic offense will be specific to the traffic statute for which the citation is written. "Badly damaged car" is rather vague and unlikely to be part of the statute.

Comment: Correct. It is a "Class A Traffic Infraction" in Colorado, a civil charge (not a crime).To clarify your opening statement, some traffic infractions are misdemeanors in some states- for example reckless driving can be charged for driving over a certain speed. And as you suggest some are felonies such as drunk driving, vehicular homicide, etc.